# Can someone explain the Shell Shock Bash code?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, shellshock-bash-bug

I am having problems understanding the following code, which is the Shell Shock 'proof of vulnerability' code.
Can someone explain it to me? Specially, this part "`() { :;};`"

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
```

Comment: This is the Shell Shock code.  There is at least one, probably multiple, other questions on this topic.  …OK; the other question I had in mind is more recent than this one…so now [Can someone explain how this shellshock code works in shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052189/can-someone-explain-how-this-shellshock-code-works-in-shell) is a duplicate of this.  Is there another question that should be the canonical one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"`

what `env` does?

 From the docs, `env` runs programs in modified environment

`env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]`

it clear that `x` is a name/variable and `() { :;}; echo vulnerable'` is the value fo the variable

now what is `() { :;};`?

when a function is exported, bash stores its defenition as value to the environment variable

```
$ x() {echo hello world;}
$ export x
$ env | grep x
x=() {echo hello world};
```

now when `x='() {:;}'` means similar as writing

```
$ x() {:;}
$ export x
$ env | grep x
```

That is we indirectly made `export x` onto the new environmnet created by the `env`
Here `:` is a null statement in bash

Hope it helps