# Can someone explain how this "Shellshock" code works in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, security, shellshock-bash-bug

I read in the news that [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) is another bigger vulnerability after [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed).
The code to test if our [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) shell is vulnerable or not is:

```
env X="() { :;} ; echo shellshock" /bin/sh -c "echo completed"
```

In detail, how does this code exactly work? What does the code `env X="() { :;} ;` do?

How is it vulnerable and can it be exploited if I am hosting a website in a Linux environment where the shell is vulnerable?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/68122/45915 is a good start.

Answer (score 4):

`env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"`

What does `env` do?

From the documentation, `env` runs programs in a modified environment.

```
env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

It is clear that `x` is a name/variable and `() { :;}; echo vulnerable'` is the value for the variable.

Now, what is `() { :;};`?

When a function is exported, Bash stores its defenition as a value in the environment variable:

```
$ x() {echo hello world;}
$ export x
$ env | grep x
x=() {echo hello world};
```

Now, when `x='() {:;}'` means similar as writing

```
$ x() {:;}
$ export x
$ env | grep x
```

That is, we indirectly made `export x` onto the new environmnet created by the `env`. Here `:` is a null statement in Bash.